# How to use & in mkdir when creating a new folder?

Tags: command-line

I just want to know how do I use `&` when creating a new folder using the `mkdir` command?

I was trying to create a directory as follows:

```
mkdir tests&results
```

But I am getting error that:

```
results:command not found
```

And a directory with name `tests` is created!

How do I achieve this? I have already tried:

```
mkdir tests/&/results
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
mkdir "tests&results"
```

OR

```
mkdir tests\&results
```

Comment: Ya that worked! Thanks! Btw what is escape character for shell?so that I can do this mkdir tests[ESC]&[ESC]results.

Comment: not the frontslash it's backslash.

Comment: In a Linux environment & is used to execute multiple process using a single command. when using & within a dir.. use "test & results" which will do.. :)

Comment: Ya I got it! :)

Comment: It also works if you want to name things with spaces, like "mkdir my\ pictures"

Comment: What is the reason of the second "\" ? It's enough only `mkdir tests\&results`